# Version error after pip installing MySQL-python on OSX

Tags: python, macos, pip, mysql-python

I have successfully installed `MySQL-python` to my virtual environment, confirmed by the fact that PyCharm can import it. I am however getting this message:

```
ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 4, 'beta', 4), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1)
```

My installation method has been:

- Activate my venv in the terminal
- `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`
- `export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments`
- `pip install MySQL-python`

Which returns a successful build. I really don't understand what the problem is, is `pip` serving me a corrupted directory?

I tried resolving this by googling and the likes to no avail. I then tried downloading version 1.2.4b4 from sourceforge and built it within the venv. This gives me the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.19/lib/libmysqlclient_r.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.19/lib/libmysqlclient_r.dylib
```

I have run file $(which ) on mysql and python, returning a 64 bit build for mysql and both a 32 and 64 bit build for python.

I really have no idea what to do next, I would really appreciate some  help, let me know if I've missed something! Thank you

EDIT:

I pip uninstalled MySQL-python and tried again with this zip: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

```
pip install -Iv https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip#md5=654f75b302db6ed8dc5a898c625e030c
```

Which gave me the same error as before, stating MySQLdb is version 1.2.4b4 but _mysql is 1.2.5. This leads me to believe I might have a lingering version of MySQL-python that isn't being uninstalled. How would I go about testing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of common potential issues:

- make sure your path is right and that `pip` and `python` refer to the same interpreter. Virtual environments are best activated by doing `source activate <NAME>` or prepending them to the path instead of appending.
- I had multiple issues with MySqlSB and stack overflow is full of questions about it. All my problems went away when I switched to `pymysql`, whose API is fully compatible with `mysqldb`. Even better, there is a method `install_as_MySQLdb()` which makes `pymysql` appear exactly like mysqldb, so all packages the expect the latter work with the former.

The procedure that I use to get set up on OSX is:

- get rid of all Python installations (system python, home-brew, etc)
- `brew install mysql gcc`. `gcc` is in  case you want to compile `c`/`fortran` extensions to python modules.
- Watch for permission errors- always run `brew doctor`
- install [anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)
- set up a virtual environment `conda create -n <NAME> python=3.4`
- activate virtual environment `source activate <NAME>`
- install required packages, trying `conda` first and `pip` if the package isn't there. For example, I always do `conda install numpy` so I don't have to compile it myself, and I do `pip install pymysql`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above answer, good advice for future troubleshooters. I managed to solve this by re-installing the 1.2.5 build and restarting my compiler.

In other words, the method I outlined above should work. For future reference make sure your bin/activate and bin/pip have their paths set to your venv and not someone else on your developer team